# some doubts about type long or other type

Tags: c++

1.
 Is it possible to display the content of an `int` or `float` or `long`, etc.?
I mean for example:
The int is `8B`. And it contains 64 bits. So, I would like to change the second bit for example.

For instance:
`int a = 64;`
I'd like to change bits and watch it in console:
`000000000000....01000001`.

2.
If there are any difference between `int` and for example `long` (eventually `byte`) expect length?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc

Comment: @EdCottrell I know, sometimes we simply don't pay attention :) But recently I'm trying to pay the attention of the editor in such cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question simply use a `std::bitset` and stream that to `std::cout`.  Something like:

```
int a = 64;
std::bitset<sizeof(int) * 8> x(a);
std::cout << x;
```

For your second, `long` is guaranteed by the standard to not be smaller than `int` and they're both integral types.

Comment: `std::binary` isn't a manipulator, and doesn't affect formatting. It's an `openmode` flag, for specifying binary mode rather than text mode.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ooops, my bad! Fixed my answer to something hopefully more C++

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the first question, but for the second question it is guaranteed that `sizeof(char)` is 1 and `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)`.